# How to use htaccess variable to set a php value dynamically?

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-log

I want to turn error logging on and the hosting suggests to use the error_log directive in the htaccess file for not choosing the default path and name.

My need is to create and set a dynamic filename by date like:

`error_log_%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}.txt`

Despite the variables above are correct, the file created is the following:

`error_log_%25{TIME_YEAR}-%25{TIME_MON}-%25{TIME_DAY}.txt`

The code in the htaccess file is the following:

```
# log PHP errors to a file
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_reporting 32767
php_value error_log /path/to/log/error_log_%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}.txt
```

Is there a way to use these variables to use in a path dynamically?

Comment: If there isn't, you can always just parse the log file and display it any way you'd like, e.g. by month.

Comment: You could achieve what your trying to accomplish when you create a PHP page dedicated for error handling and you can just call `error_log` on it with current date and or anything your like for the filename

Comment: You could theoretically set the path yourself _in_ a PHP script, and then use `auto_prepend_file` to get that little script executed before all other scripts automatically. That will of course only be able to catch runtime errors that occur _after_ this script has been embedded, anything else that might happen during startup of course won't be logged in _that_ file then, but whatever the specified default is. And I am not sure how it reacts regarding parse errors in your normal scripts, whether that would prevent the prepended script from running as well, you'd have to test.